# Where I found out milliseconds for the execution of a query in SQL Server 2008 management studio?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Where I found out milliseconds for the execution of a query in SQL Server 2008 Management Studio?

In Actual Execution Plan I cannot see the time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use [SET STATISTICS TIME ON/OFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190287.aspx) in beginning and end of query

Answer (score 1):

Several places:

- [`sys.dm_exec_query_stats`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189741.aspx) has `last_worker_time` and `last_elapsed_time`
- [SQL:StmtCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189886.aspx) captures `Duration`
- Ditto for [RPC:Completed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175543.aspx)
- Ditto for [SP:StmtCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189570.aspx)
- `set statistics time on` as Jack already pointed out
- [XEvents](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/category/xevent-a-day-series/) track basically *everything* and more.

Answer (score -1):

```
 CultureInfo newCulture = (CultureInfo)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
 newCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "MM-dd-yyyy";
 newCulture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "-";
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
```